# attribute and private attribute difference in Python property?

Tags: python, properties

```
class test:              #1
 def __init__(self):     #2
    self.abc = 123       #3
 @property               #4
 def abc(self):          #5
    return self._abc     #6

 @abc.setter             #7
 def abc(self, value):   #8
    self._abc = value    #9

 @abc.deleter            #10
 def abc(self):          #11
    del self._abc        #12

obj = test()             #13
obj.abc = 456            #14
print(obj.abc)           #15
```

---

```
class test:              #1
 def __init__(self):     #2
    self._abc = 123      #3
 @property               #4
 def abc(self):          #5
    return self._abc     #6

 @abc.setter             #7
 def abc(self, value):   #8
    self._abc = value    #9

 @abc.deleter            #10
 def abc(self):          #11
    del self._abc        #12

obj = test()             #13
obj.abc = 456            #14
print(obj.abc)           #15
```

what is the difference between the self._abc and self.abc in **init** method?

The output of these two programs maybe the same but the code behavior is different.

frist program run: 13-2-3-7-9-3-14-7-9-15-4-6

second program run :13-2-3-14-7-9-15-4-6

why?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most experienced coder, but from what I've seen, Python doesn't explicitly have public or private attributes, all class variables / methods are accessible all the time.

The underscore in self._abc is more a "developer's unwritten rule", the underscore is used to make an attribute "private" - it technically isn't, but other developers will see it and treat it as private. The other self.abc() functions are public getters / setters / deleters for that "private" variable.

Again, this isn't defined by Python, so someone could easily call self._abc and modify it, and it would compile and run - but it's poor practice to do so.

Comment: My bad. I wan't  describe clearly about my question.I edited it.

Comment: No worries.

For your updated question: in your test class, there is a private variable _abc (with underscore) and abc() acts as getter/setter functions for the private variable _abc. 

In the first program, the init function modifies _abc via the public setter function abc, so init -> setter abc() -> self._abc. In the second program, the init function bypasses the setter function abc and directly modifies _abc, so init -> self._abc. 

Try this analogy - turn off your PC with Start -> Shut Down, or press the Power button. One way uses a pre-defined button click, the other bypasses that.